# Remote Connection to Neo4j Server 3.2

Tags: neo4j

Currently, I tried to connect Neo4j Server which is hosted on remote Machine so What are the configuration file changes(Neo4j.conf) changes I have to do for this?

I referred some the question and done changes as per that but still I am not able to connect to remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to uncomment this line from the `conf/neo4j.conf` file :

```
dbms.connectors.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0
```